# Ternary Operator for PaddingLeft with MUI

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

In my application, I want the **paddingLeft** of the container to change if the side nav menu is selected open or closed.
There is a variable `open` that determines if the side nav is open.

**What I tried:**
When rendering the container, I added a `sx` which would set the padding accordingly.

```
<Container maxWidth={false} className={classes.container} 
  sx = {{paddingLeft: open ? "theme.spacing(34)" : "theme.spacing(200)"}}>
```

However, nothing is occurring; **no padding is being applied**.
Am I misusing the sx or is there a way this can be done with the style tag?

Comment: Maybe `sx={ theme => ({ paddingLeft: theme.spacing(open ? 34 : 200})}`?

Comment: Nothing happens when I do that either and i tried  sx={ theme => ({ paddingLeft: theme.spacing(open ? 34 : 200)}) }

Comment: Be a great idea to include that kind of information in your question so people don't suggest things you've already verified don't work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`theme` is a prop which means you can't pass it like a string using double quotes. Try to use string interpolation instead.

```
<Container maxWidth={false} className={classes.container} 
  sx = {{paddingLeft: open ? `${theme.spacing(34)}` : `${theme.spacing(200)}`}}>
```

or just remove double quotes

```
<Container maxWidth={false} className={classes.container} 
  sx = {{paddingLeft: open ? theme.spacing(34) : theme.spacing(200)}}>
```

Update: fix undefined theme.

```
<Container maxWidth={false} className={classes.container} 
  sx = {{ paddingLeft: (theme) => open ?  theme.spacing(34) : theme.spacing(200) }}>
```

Comment: I am getting an error that says theme is not defined

Comment: using both snippet? what if you try numbers first, just to check if `sx` works or not.

Comment: I am getting theme is not defined for both suggestions.

Comment: When I tried checking for numbers, sx = {{paddingLeft: open ? "300px" : "200px"}} nothing happened either

Comment: can you try the update I made above?

Comment: No errors, but no padding changes made.

Comment: you check this one , it is working https://codesandbox.io/s/fixedcontainer-demo-material-ui-forked-2mkb3e?file=/demo.js

Comment: but that one using margin